# Не могу запустить веб-приложение на pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, django, bash, хостинг, pythonanywhere

Я впервые на форуме и вообще начинающий в Python и вебе. Искал я хостинг для своего веб-приложения, знакомый кодер посоветовал pythonanywhere.com, он сам там держит.

Ну я взял там бесплатный хостинг, питон 3.7 + фреймворк Django. Далее я запустил консоль Bash (линукс походу). Действую я в основном по гайду от Хауди Хо "Django за час". Пытаюсь запустить следующие команды:

```
python manage.py runserver
python manage.py startapp articles
```

При вводе этих команд даёт ошибку (скрин ниже).

Я вижу, что Bash ругается на синтакс, ошибку в коде manage.py, думаю команду надо вводить по-другому как-то, ведь это не cmd.exe. Помогите понять какие команды надо вводить, чтобы все заработало как надо. Или может есть какая-то конкретная инструкция?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том, что нужно было писать не `python`, а `python3`.

Answer (score -3):

В баше тебе нужно установить модули. pip3 install название_модуля --user.
3 в конце pip обязательна, --user тоже обязательна!
Нужно установить все модули которые ты используешь, кроме дефолтных(random, time, т.д).
После этого запуск командой python3 название_файла.py

Comment: Так я ещё даже код не успел написать для своего приложения. Мне консоль не даёт всё подготовить (не создаёт приложение).